# How to create the Luigi dependency diagram when running local-scheduler

Tags: python

I have implemented some tasks within the luigi framework, and now I want to visualize the dependency diagram.

My coworker instructed me to start the luigid by

```
luigid mkdir -p luigi;--background --logdir luigi --state-path luigi/state --address 0.0.0.0 --port 32145
```

After that, I could see the task visualizer in chrome browser localhost:32145

Then I run the the luigi task

```
python luigi_scheduler.py --local-scheduler
```

the luigi_scheduler runs the task by the following line

```
luigi.run(main_task_cls = someTaskA)
```

Then I got the following msg and the tasks are finished. Yet nothing appeared on the task visualizer.

```
DEBUG: Checking if get_usr_activity_all() is complete
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/luigi/task.py:433: UserWarning: Task get_usr_activity_all() without outputs has no custom complete() method
warnings.warn("Task %r without outputs has no custom complete() method" % self)
INFO: Scheduled get_usr_activity_all() (PENDING)
DEBUG: Checking if get_usr_hw(n=33000) is complete
INFO: Scheduled get_usr_hw(n=33000) (DONE)
DEBUG: Checking if get_usr_login(n=33000) is complete
INFO: Scheduled get_usr_login(n=33000) (DONE)
INFO: Done scheduling tasks
INFO: Running Worker with 1 processes
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 1
INFO: [pid 16937] Worker Worker(salt=675435319, host=ubuntu, username=junchen, pid=16937) running   get_usr_activity_all()
INFO: [pid 16937] Worker Worker(salt=675435319, host=ubuntu, username=junchen, pid=16937) done      get_usr_activity_all()
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
INFO: Done
INFO: There are no more tasks to run at this time
INFO: Worker Worker(salt=675435319, host=ubuntu, username=junchen, pid=16937) was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is impossible. The webinterface/GUI is run by the central scheduler, so if it isn't aware of running tasks it cannot give you that information.

Comment: Yes, you are right. the dependency graph is only available for central scheduler. I should read the documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 6):

I am aware this is an old question, but for anyone landing there, there is actually a way to visualize the dependency tree of a task independent of any scheduler, provided by the [luigi.tools.deps_tree](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.tools.deps_tree.html) module.

Assuming you run luigi with:

```py
luigi.run(main_task_cls = someTaskA)
```

you can get your script to print the dependency tree of `someTaskA` by adding the following before run:

```py
import luigi.tools.deps_tree as deps_tree

print(deps_tree.print_tree(someTaskA))
```

Which will print something like this to the console:

```
└─--[Foo-{} (PENDING)]
   |--[Bar-{'num': '0'} (PENDING)]
   |  |--[Bar-{'num': '4'} (PENDING)]
   |  └─--[Bar-{'num': '5'} (PENDING)]
   |--[Bar-{'num': '1'} (PENDING)]
   └─--[Bar-{'num': '2'} (PENDING)]
      └─--[Bar-{'num': '6'} (PENDING)]
         |--[Bar-{'num': '7'} (PENDING)]
         |  |--[Bar-{'num': '9'} (PENDING)]
         |  └─--[Bar-{'num': '10'} (PENDING)]
         |     └─--[Bar-{'num': '11'} (PENDING)]
         └─--[Bar-{'num': '8'} (PENDING)]
            └─--[Bar-{'num': '12'} (PENDING)]
```

Where `Foo` and `Bar` are task names, and the dicts `{'num': 'x'}` are the parameters of those tasks.

I found this particularly useful, in particular for debugging complex workflows with lots of parameters.